# How to redirect to app after successful facebook log in in android?

Tags: android, facebook

In my android application I am sharing something in facebook throw facebook android API.This is working fine .But after successful sharing the app displaying a black screen.How to avoid that black screen?
I want to redirect to my application after successful share

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK for android..? Put some code for Activity that is calling for authentication and not working as expected..

Answer (score 1):

After login , method named OnComplete() is called. So, fire your intent in this method.

Like this-->

```
 public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
 {
  # fire desired intent      
 }
```